# GTest: How to pass variable to forked process in death test when using "threadsafe" style

Tags: c++, unit-testing, tdd, googletest

I am trying to write a death test to verify that a log file contains an expected output after the program runs into a segmentation fault. Since the program is multi-threaded, I have to use the "threadsafe" death-test style (our team has observed deadlocks in similar tests otherwise). The problem is that when using this style, I cannot get the child process created for the death test to read a value that was set in the parent process, as it would normally be the case after a fork/clone in the "fast" style.

The following example illustrates the problem, and I am using the process PID as an example. The goal here is to get the same value printed in the "inside" as well as in the "outside after" messages.

```cpp
 #include <iostream>
 #include <gtest/gtest.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 using namespace std;

 void makeSegfault() {
     volatile int* x = nullptr;
     int a = *x;
 }

 static int pid = getpid();

 TEST(MyDeathTest, DeathTestExample)
 {
      // Comment this line to get the same pid in every message
      testing::FLAGS_gtest_death_test_style = "threadsafe";
      cout << "pid outside before " << pid << endl;
      ASSERT_EXIT(
              cout << "pid inside " << pid << endl;
              makeSegfault(),
              testing::KilledBySignal(SIGSEGV), ".*");
      cout << "pid outside after " << pid << endl;
  }
```

The output without "threadsafe" (behaves as expected -- same pid everywhere):

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyDeathTest
[ RUN      ] MyDeathTest.DeathTestExample
pid outside before 96698
pid inside 96698
pid outside after 96698
[       OK ] MyDeathTest.DeathTestExample (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyDeathTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (1 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

and with "threadsafe" (path hidden with `[...]`):

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from MyDeathTest
[ RUN      ] MyDeathTest.DeathTestExample
pid outside before 96854
Running main() from [...]/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
pid outside before 96855
pid inside 96855
pid outside after 96854
[       OK ] MyDeathTest.DeathTestExample (3 ms)
[----------] 1 test from MyDeathTest (3 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (3 ms total)
```

I understand that this might be expected due to how the "threadsafe" mode runs the whole test again, as stated in the documentation:

> the child process re-executes the unit test binary just as it was originally invoked, but with some extra flags to cause just the single death test under consideration to be run

But in that case, how can I make sure that the inner process and the outer process can use the same value for any given static variable?

Comment: If the value absolutely must be generated in the parent and propagated to the child (as opposed to being something that can be reliably re-calculated on demand), then I think you'll have to go through the OS with a memory file or something along these lines.

Comment: @S.M. I don't know. If OP could just pass the value as an argument when invoking the test, they might as well just use a constant instead. It feels like there's some hidden complexity about how the expected value is determined that we are not seing.

Comment: I think it's also worth pointing out that non-constant global/static variables in test code is a good candidate for the dictionary entry of "asking for trouble".

Comment: @S.M. Your proposed answer could be a workaround, but it does not address the particular issue of my question. The issue here is more about the interaction of the thread-safe death-test style and the state of local or static variables in the surrounding code. 

As Frank pointed out, the value is not a constant that I can pass via command line. It is rather something generated in the test itself. The example code illustrates that. If you can make my example code work, you've solved my question. Thanks for the input, nevertheless.